# Install Shield LE - Error 6058 ... merging Visual C++ 10.0 CRT in 64bit

Tags: visual-c++, installshield-le

I'm trying to compile an install shield project. It's a 64 bit program.
I keep getting this error, although it does compile OK and installs OK:

```
Error   16  -6058: Error merging Visual C++ 10.0 CRT (IA64) with module ID C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC100_CRT_ia64.msm   ISEXP : error : -6058: Error merging Visual C++ 10.0 CRT (IA64) with module ID C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC100_CRT_ia64.msm
```

Any idea how can tell it NOT to try and merge ? (I can let it install the CRT ad a redistributable instead)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so it's like this:

Was detected as a dependency by mistake:

> Adding merge module 'Visual C++ 10.0
>   CRT (IA64)' that is a dependency of
>   component
>   'MyProjectName.Primary_output'

So you go to:

**Specify application Data -> Files**

Right click on the specified project that had the dependency.
Choose **Dependencies from scan at build..** find that unwanted file, and uncheck it.

Comment: Also, if you do in fact need the C++ runtime,  it's a better pratice to use the provided Setup Prerequisite rather then including it as a merge module.  This allows Microsoft to better service ( patch ) it.  It does require the use of the setup.exe bootstrapper though.

Answer (score 2):

Some Installshield products (2010, 2011 at least) appear to have an issue scanning managed (/clr) c++ modules that use the 10.0 CRT, even for 32-bit-only projects. In those cases the IA64 msm gets added to the project, producing "error -5008: Intel64 or AMD64 must be specified in the template of the Summary Stream".  Yochai's fix cured that too. I have not seen this issue for native c++ code.