# InstallShield giving ISEXP : error : -5008 when building setup project in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, 32bit-64bit, setup-project, installshield-2012, merge-module

I have .net project which I converted from VS 2010 to VS 2012. I am building a setup for the project through InstallShield Limited Edition but I get following error.

ISEXP : error : -5008: This 32-bit package cannot include 64-bit data. The 64-bit data may come from a merge module.

I have searched a lot but could not find any specific solution to my problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You aren't providing much information to go on. Do you include merge modules? Do you scan for dependencies? What sort of files does your project have and what dependencies might they have?

Comment: Michael many thanks for your response. I solved the problem. For some unknown reasons my setup was including VC merge module of 64bit and I did not need that. So I removed that from the dependencies in the setup project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolved this issue by removing the Visual C++ Runtime dependency on the project output. Here's how to do it:

(2)Specify applicaiton data / Files / right click on the primary output / dependencies from scan at build

There you can uncheck all dependencies that cause problem, Uncheck `Visual C++ 10.0 CRT (x64)`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5392746/2498426)

I also had a -6109 Internal Build error which was caused by a dependency. I just unchecked it there. It took me a whole business day to figure that cryptic stuff out. This is insane and frustrating for the least.